# Force Openvpn client internet traffic not go thru vpnserver

Tags: openvpn

By default, the Openvpn client's internet traffic goes thru VPNserver, is there any way to force it route thru the local interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not "by default". It depends on the configuration sent by the VPN server when the connection is established.

`opnvpn` has many parameters related to routing. You can complement the routing after starting `opnvpn`, the ultimate option is `--route-nopull` that prevents your `openvpn` tunnel to set any  routing.

On the server side, an openvpn server config sets up routes on the client using `push "route <subnet address> <subnet mask">` statements, so its is only a matter of defining routing through the VPN for specific subnets instead of having an all-encompassing routing. Note that the way it works makes it difficult to exclude specific address ranges from the server side.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Is there anyway to do it at server side?

Comment: See augmented answer...